# How to remove my created pod specifications

Tags: cocoapods

I've created a pod specification for learning, and now I'd like to remove it as it is shown under my name when searching for pods. I've looked everywhere in the documentation and couldn't find how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CocoaPods doesn't support pod deletions, you should release a new version with the deprecated flag set. We're working on figuring out how to [support deletions](https://github.com/CocoaPods/trunk.cocoapods.org/pull/144), but it's a long process and we want to ensure it's right.